# How to query the result of rand in a php loop?

Tags: php, variables, logic

I am beginning to learn PHP. Here I am trying to create a loop that checks whether a randomly generated number is 50. If the number is 50, I want to print "it's 50!", if not, I want to echo the result, then repeat the random generation.

Here is my code:

```
    <?php
        $number = 0; // sets the number to 0
        while ($number != 50) {  // I want this loop to repeat when the result isn't 50
            echo $number; // print the result
            $number = rand(0,100); // reshuffle
            if ($number == 50) { // result for if 50 is the result
                echo "it's 50!";
            }
            else { // result otherwise
                $number = 0;
            }
        }
    ?>
```

I feel like it's not working because I don't redefine $number based on the result of the rand function, is this correct? If so, how do I redefine the value of the $number variable from within the loop?

Comment: In what way is it not working? The main thing I notice is that you keep resetting $number to 0 if it's not 50, which serves no purpose and means you'll output "0" anytime it's not 50.

Comment: So it seems the code works in some PHP previewers but not the one I was using, which kept giving an error message. So perhaps a better question for me to ask is what is the best way to test code while learning?

Comment: Which previewer were you using?  What was your error message? Your code 'works' but doesn't output each random number in the loop, rather it outputs 0, until it hits 50.

Comment: The previewer on CodeAcademy just outputted 0it's50 every time, always just one zero which didn't make sense. Other previewers displayed a random amount of zeros, then random numbers once I stopped redefining $number as zero.

Comment: Best guess in that you had `$number = 50` instead of the comparison operator.  I did wonder if their previewer seeded the random generator, and by chance you were getting a 50 on the second call to rand each time.  But didn't look like that when I just used it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue with the code you have submitted is that, if your randomly picked number is not 50 you then assign 0 to it.  So your output will be a stream of 0s.

You can modify your code slightly, and drop your else block:

```
<?php
$number = null;
while ($number != 50) {
    $number = rand(0, 100);
    echo $number . "\n";
    if ($number == 50)
        echo "It's 50!";
}
```

Or, just loop until you strike your number, then break out.

```
<?php
while (true) {
    $number = rand(0, 100);
    echo "$number\n";
    if ($number == 50) {
        echo "it's 50!\n";
        break;
    }
}
```

Or even simpler:

```
while (($number = rand(0, 100)) != 50)
    echo "$number\n";

echo "It's 50!";
```

Comment: What does the \n mean?

Comment: @ChrisL, `\n` is interpreted (within the double quotes), as a *nix new line character.  It represents a line feed.  It's so the output is readable, and not one long string.  e.g. 44523311.

Comment: Incredible. Thanks for all your help here!